# Click in iframe register parent window

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage where I have an Iframe. When someone clicks something in the Iframe I want to detect it in the parent window.

I see there are similar threads in the forum but no one solved my issue.

Zolka

Comment: Did you try `window.parent.window.alert`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the jQuery `.contents()` method to retrieve the contents of the iFrame, and then search within that for your `.click1` elements.

See the following jQuery code (works in v1.7 up):

```
$('#1_iframe').load(function() {
    $(this).contents().find('#myGrid').on('click', '.click1', function() {
        alert('Click detected!');
    });
});
```

EDIT: Wrapped it in a `.load()` event handler.

Comment: I have another question: When I want to modify the contents of div I use this code: $('#2_iframe').contents().find('div#ShoppingCartProducts').text('111111111'); But it works only when I wrap it in a 'setTimeout' function. Probably I have to wait untill the iframe is loaded and only after that can I modify it's content. Do you know maybe an alternative for setTimeout?

Comment: Yes, use the `.load()` event for the iframe - I have updated my answer to show you how in this case.

Comment: @Zolka Also, be sure to [mark this answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Attach a event on the iframe

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
   var targ = e.currentTarget();

   //Now send this to the parent function
   parent.NewClick(targ);
});
```

Now the `NewClick()` function in the parent window, will know which button was clicked.